# List each day in the SELECT clause of Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I have an Access database with the following table.

```
tblFaultCall
------------
ID : Autonumber
strName
strPhone
dtmDateOpen : Date/Time (date call logged)
dtmDateClosed : Date/Time (date call closed)
dtmTime : Date/Time (time call logged)
strStatus (always 'Open', 'Pending' or 'Closed')
strCategory (always one of 10 categories, held as as list in tblCatgory, and used in lookup lists in the ASP web page)
strFaultDesc 
strResolution
strCallOwner
dtmDatePending : Date/Time (date call set to pending, if it ever was)
```

Calls come in as Open. If user sets to pending, the dtmDatePending is populated with the current date.
If the user sets the call to Closed when it's completed, the dtmDateClosed is populated with the current date.
Not all calls are set to pending.
some days, users do not change status of calls because they are doing other things. Also, no activity at weekends.

I want to monitor the call ownder's activity.

I have a query as below (in a classic ASP within a loop which goes through each user, variable strCallOwner, dates are set by the user in previous page)

```
SELECT dtmDateClosed, Count(ID) AS CallsClosed 
FROM tblFaultCall " 
WHERE strCallOwner = """ & strCallOwner & """ 
GROUP BY dtmDateClosed 
HAVING dtmDateClosed BETWEEN  #"& FromMonth & "/" & FromDay & "/" & FromYear &"# and #"& ToMonth & "/" & ToDay & "/" & ToYear &"#
```

This is fine, and gives me output such as below

```
Day Calls Closed
09/04/2014  4
15/04/2014  4
16/04/2014  2
25/04/2014  1
30/04/2014  1
01/05/2014  7
```

We need to clearly see where users have not done any activity. So, I want to be able to show every day in the period in the HAVING clause (even where no calls Closed that day, and if its a weekend, I want something in the results to indicate it's a weekend day). I also want an additional column for number of calls pended based on dtmDatePending.

I want it to look something like this

```
Day         Calls Closed    Calls Pended
Wed 09/04/14    4           0
Thu 10/04/14    0           0
Fri 11/04/14    0           1
Sat 12/04/14    -           -
Sun 13/04/14    -           -
Mon 14/04/14    0           1
Tue 15/04/14    0           0
Wed 16/04/14    2           1
```

I am populating a table in the ASP, but really it's the query that I'm stuck with.

I know I need outer joins for the second and third columns, but I need to know how to create a list of days for the first column. I not know if this is possible in an Access query? I may have to use an array in the ASP? Or create an additional table in the database?

Thanks.

Edit - Thanks to the responses thus far, I have got a working version which gives me the CallsClosed, as below

```
SELECT d.dtmDate, Count(fc.ID) AS CallsClosed
FROM [select distinct dtmDateClosed as dtmDate
      from tblFaultCall
      where dtmDateClosed BETWEEN #5/20/14# and #5/30/14#
     ]. AS d LEFT JOIN [select fc.*
      from tblFaultCall as fc
      where fc.strCallOwner = 'Ben Hamilton'
     ]. AS fc ON fc.dtmDateClosed = d.dtmDate
GROUP BY d.dtmDate
ORDER BY d.dtmDate;
```

This reports

```
dtmDate     CallsClosed
20/05/2014  5
21/05/2014  16
22/05/2014  0
23/05/2014  5
27/05/2014  0
28/05/2014  5
29/05/2014  2
30/05/2014  2
```

These numbers are correct as I've cross checked.

However, I have tried to amend this to include another column for pended cases, as below

```
SELECT d.dtmDate, Count(fc.ID) AS CallsClosed, COUNT(fp.ID) AS CallsPended
FROM ([select distinct dtmDateClosed as dtmDate
      from tblFaultCall
      where dtmDateClosed BETWEEN #5/20/14# and #5/30/14#
     ]. AS d LEFT JOIN [select fc.*
      from tblFaultCall as fc
      where fc.strCallOwner = 'Ben Hamilton' AND fc.strStatus = 'Closed'
     ]. AS fc ON fc.dtmDateClosed = d.dtmDate) LEFT JOIN [SELECT fp.ID, fp.dtmDatePending
FROM tblFaultCall AS fp 
WHERE fp.strCallOwner = 'Ben Hamilton' ]. AS fp ON fp.dtmDatePending = d.dtmDate
GROUP BY d.dtmDate
ORDER BY d.dtmDate;
```

This runs, but for some reason reports incorrect figures :-

```
dtmDate     CallsClosed CallsPended
20/05/2014  4           0
21/05/2014  16          0
22/05/2014  0           0
23/05/2014  15          15
27/05/2014  0           0
28/05/2014  20          20
29/05/2014  2           0
30/05/2014  2           0
```

For 23/05/14, it should report 5 Closed calls, and 3 pending. Other days are wrong too.

Edit 11/07/14

The SQL provided by @Gord Thompson works well. But I am struggling with the parameter query. Part of the problem is that I am looping through another recordset containing list of users;

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<%' Option Explicit %>  
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>Fault Call - User Activity Stats</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<% 

Dim FCConnString, FCConn

FCConnString="PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _ 
    "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("/bactu/spoc/db/FaultCall.mdb") 

set FCConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
FCConn.Open(FCConnString)

Dim RSUserDays, SQLUserDays, cmdUserDays 'As ADODB.Command
Dim FromDay, FromMonth, FromTo, ToDay, ToMonth, ToYear
Dim RSUserList, SQLUserList, strCallOwner
Const adParamInput = 1
Const adDBDate = 133
const adVarWChar = 202

FromDay = Request.QueryString("from_day")
FromMonth = Request.QueryString("from_month")
FromYear = Request.QueryString("from_year")

ToDay = Request.QueryString("to_day")
ToMonth = Request.QueryString("to_month")
ToYear = Request.QueryString("to_year")

SQLUserList = "SELECT strCallOwner FROM tblCallOwner WHERE ID in (6, 12, 20, 21, 28, 30)"

SQLUserDays = "SELECT d.dtmDate, fc.ClosedCount, fp.PendingCount " & _
        "FROM " & _
            "( " & _
                "( " & _
                    "SELECT DISTINCT dtmDateOpen AS dtmDate " & _
                    "FROM tblFaultCall " & _
                    "WHERE dtmDateOpen BETWEEN ? AND ? " & _
                ") AS d " & _
                "LEFT JOIN " & _
                "( " & _
                    "SELECT dtmDateClosed, COUNT(*) AS ClosedCount " & _
                    "FROM tblFaultCall " & _
                    "WHERE strCallOwner = ? " & _
                    "GROUP BY dtmDateClosed " & _
                ") AS fc ON d.dtmDate = fc.dtmDateClosed " & _
            ") " & _
            "LEFT JOIN " & _
            "( " & _
                "SELECT dtmDatePending, COUNT(*) AS PendingCount " & _
                "FROM tblFaultCall " & _
                "WHERE strCallOwner = ? " & _
                "GROUP BY dtmDatePending " & _
            ") AS fp ON d.dtmDate = fp.dtmDatePending"

'Create and Open Recordset for UserList
Set RSUserList = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RSUserList.Open SQLUserList, FCConn, 3, 3

'create ADODB.Command object cmdUserDays and set CommandText, ActiveConnection properties
Set cmdUserDays = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmdUserDays.ActiveConnection = FCConn
cmdUserDays.CommandText = SQLUserDays

'Append cmdUserDays parameters - CreateParameter(Name, Type, Direction, SizeIfString, Value)
cmdUserDays.Parameters.Append cmdUserDays.CreateParameter("QueryFromDate", adDBDate, adParamInput, , DateSerial(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay))
cmdUserDays.Parameters.Append cmdUserDays.CreateParameter("QueryToDate", adDBDate, adParamInput, , DateSerial(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay))

'we do not know the strCallOwner yet, but must assign, so default value of "Nothing")
cmdUserDays.Parameters.Append cmdUserDays.CreateParameter("QueryCallOwner1", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, "Nothing")
cmdUserDays.Parameters.Append cmdUserDays.CreateParameter("QueryCallOwner2", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, "Nothing")

'create recordset from command's execute method
Set RSUserDays = cmdUserDays.Execute

'Iterate through RSUserList using a DO loop, display tables
Do While Not RSUserList.EOF 
strCallOwner = RSUserList("strCallOwner")

'set the 2 command params for call owner, re-execute command - I think this is the bit which is not working
cmdUserDays("QueryCallOwner1") = strCallOwner
cmdUserDays("QueryCallOwner2") = strCallOwner
Set RSUserDays = cmdUserDays.Execute

%>

<b><%=RSUserList("strCallOwner")%></b>
<%'Response.Write(cmdUserDays.CommandText)%>
<table border="1px">        
    <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Calls Closed</th>   
        <th>Calls Pended</th>
    </tr>
    <%Do While not RSUserDays.EOF %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= RSUserDays("dtmDate")%>
        <% DayOfWeek = DatePart("W", RSUserDays("dtmDate"))

        Select Case DayOfWeek
        Case 1 Response.Write " Sun"
        Case 2 Response.Write " Mon"
        Case 3 Response.Write " Tue"
        Case 4 Response.Write " Wed"
        Case 5 Response.Write " Thu"
        Case 6 Response.Write " Fri"
        Case 7 Response.Write " Sat"
        End Select%></td>

        <td><%= RSUserDays("ClosedCount") %></td>       
        <td><%= RSUserDays("PendingCount") %></td>
    </tr>
    <%RSUserDays.MoveNext 
    Loop
    %>
</table>

<%
RSUserDays.Close
RSUserList.MoveNext 
Loop

Set RSUserDays = Nothing

RSUserList.Close
Set RSUserList = Nothing

Set cmdUserDays = Nothing

FCConn.Close
Set FCConn = Nothing

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=excelTest.xls"
%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Runs fine but returns empty results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gives us the "Closed" counts

```sql
SELECT dtmDateClosed, COUNT(*) AS ClosedCount
FROM tblFaultCall
WHERE strCallOwner = 'Ben Hamilton'
GROUP BY dtmDateClosed
```

This query gives us the "Pending" counts

```sql
SELECT dtmDatePending, COUNT(*) AS PendingCount
FROM tblFaultCall
WHERE strCallOwner = 'Ben Hamilton'
GROUP BY dtmDatePending
```

To list all the dates in the desired range along with the "Closed" counts would be

```sql
SELECT d.dtmDate, fc.ClosedCount
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT dtmDateOpen AS dtmDate
        FROM tblFaultCall 
        WHERE dtmDateOpen BETWEEN #2014-05-20# AND #2014-05-30#
    ) AS d
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT dtmDateClosed, COUNT(*) AS ClosedCount
        FROM tblFaultCall
        WHERE strCallOwner = 'Ben Hamilton'
        GROUP BY dtmDateClosed
    ) AS fc
        ON d.dtmDate = fc.dtmDateClosed
```

To incorporate the "Pending" counts would be

```sql
SELECT d.dtmDate, fc.ClosedCount, fp.PendingCount
FROM
    (
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT dtmDateOpen AS dtmDate
            FROM tblFaultCall 
            WHERE dtmDateOpen BETWEEN #2014-05-20# AND #2014-05-30#
        ) AS d
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT dtmDateClosed, COUNT(*) AS ClosedCount
            FROM tblFaultCall
            WHERE strCallOwner = 'Ben Hamilton'
            GROUP BY dtmDateClosed
        ) AS fc
            ON d.dtmDate = fc.dtmDateClosed
    )
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT dtmDatePending, COUNT(*) AS PendingCount
        FROM tblFaultCall
        WHERE strCallOwner = 'Ben Hamilton'
        GROUP BY dtmDatePending
    ) AS fp
        ON d.dtmDate = fp.dtmDatePending
```

To wrap that up in VBScript code and use a proper parameterized query would be

```vbs
Option Explicit

Dim con  ' As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd  ' As ADODB.Command
Dim rst  ' As ADODB.Recordset
Const adParamInput = 1
Const adDBDate = 133
const adVarWChar = 202

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb"

' test data
Const FromYear = 2014
Const FromMonth = 5
Const FromDay = 20
Const ToYear = 2014
Const ToMonth = 5
Const ToDay = 30
Const strCallOwner = "Ben Hamilton"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = _
        "SELECT d.dtmDate, fc.ClosedCount, fp.PendingCount " & _
        "FROM " & _
            "( " & _
                "( " & _
                    "SELECT DISTINCT dtmDateOpen AS dtmDate " & _
                    "FROM tblFaultCall " & _
                    "WHERE dtmDateOpen BETWEEN ? AND ? " & _
                ") AS d " & _
                "LEFT JOIN " & _
                "( " & _
                    "SELECT dtmDateClosed, COUNT(*) AS ClosedCount " & _
                    "FROM tblFaultCall " & _
                    "WHERE strCallOwner = ? " & _
                    "GROUP BY dtmDateClosed " & _
                ") AS fc ON d.dtmDate = fc.dtmDateClosed " & _
            ") " & _
            "LEFT JOIN " & _
            "( " & _
                "SELECT dtmDatePending, COUNT(*) AS PendingCount " & _
                "FROM tblFaultCall " & _
                "WHERE strCallOwner = ? " & _
                "GROUP BY dtmDatePending " & _
            ") AS fp ON d.dtmDate = fp.dtmDatePending"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adDBDate, adParamInput, , DateSerial(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay))
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adDBDate, adParamInput, , DateSerial(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay))
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, strCallOwner)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, strCallOwner)

Set rst = cmd.Execute
Do Until rst.EOF
    WScript.Echo rst(0).Value & "  " & rst(1).Value & "  " & rst(2).Value
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks. SQL works, but struggling with parameter query. Have amended the original question with details.

Comment: Ah, I have realised why it did not work. The CreateParameter method expects a date for the periods, but your code used DateSerial(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay). This did not work because it was expecting the month to be first, then day, then year. So, I had to amend it to "DateSerial(FromYear, FromDay, FromMonth)" and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be hard to do in Access. However, if you assume that *someone* made a call every day, then there is a solution.  I think the following will work in Access:

```
SELECT d.dtmDate, Count(fc.ID) AS CallsClosed 
FROM (select distinct dtmDateClosed as dtmDate
      from tblFaultCall
      where dtmDateClosed BETWEEN  #"& FromMonth & "/" & FromDay & "/" & FromYear &"# and #"& ToMonth & "/" & ToDay & "/" & ToYear &"#
     ) as d left join
     tblFaultCall as fc
     on fc.dtmDateClosed = d.dtmDate and
        fc.strCallOwner = """ & strCallOwner & """
GROUP BY d.dtmDate
ORDER BY d.dtmDate;
```

EDIT:

You might need to express this as:

```
SELECT d.dtmDate, Count(fc.ID) AS CallsClosed 
FROM (select distinct dtmDateClosed as dtmDate
      from tblFaultCall
      where dtmDateClosed BETWEEN  #"& FromMonth & "/" & FromDay & "/" & FromYear &"# and #"& ToMonth & "/" & ToDay & "/" & ToYear &"#
     ) as d left join
     (select fc.*
      from tblFaultCall as fc
      where fc.strCallOwner = """ & strCallOwner & """
     ) as fc
     on fc.dtmDateClosed = d.dtmDate 
GROUP BY d.dtmDate
ORDER BY d.dtmDate;
```

I recall that Access doesn't like multiple conditions in joins.

Comment: Yes, someone logs a call each workday. Do you mean to use dtmDateOpen in the FROM subselect?

Comment: The SQL does not work as it does not like the 
        fc.strCallOwner = """ & strCallOwner & """

Comment: Thx, the editted SQL works. I want another column for calls set to pending on that day (dtmDatePending) and it went wrong and started reporting the wrong amounts. I would paste my SQL here but can't in comments.

Comment: @BenHamilton you can edit your question if there has been a change.

Comment: re: "Access doesn't like multiple conditions in joins" - No, Access does indeed handle multiple conditions in joins provided that they are actual join conditions. `FieldName = 'constant'` is not an `ON` (join) condition; it is a `WHERE` condition.

Comment: @GordThompson . . . It is *not* a `where` condition in a `left join`.